# How to fix: Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget' error in Angular 8 when running ng serve or npm start

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run either 'ng serve' or 'npm start' to run my angular 8 server on localhost:4200 in cmd on a windows machine. I get a Schema error I think I know where the problem is but no idea how to fix it.

Another point to note is this was working perfectly fine until windows restarted my computer to do an update.

I'm also running tailwind through a webpack.

The main part of the error is: Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget'

```
"serve": {
   "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
   "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
         "path": "./webpack.config.js"
       }
   }
},
```

I assume I need to add browserTarget in the options here, when I do that I get an error saying I need main in there too.

Am I on the right track?
If I am, what are the values that should be attributed to these properties?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried:

- Upgrading my packages.
- Upgrading Angular
- Deleting the node modules folder and npm installing

angular.json:

```
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "bjjcastle": {
          "projectType": "application",
          "schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
              "style": "scss"
            }
          },
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "prefix": "app",
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
              "options": {
                "customWebpackConfig": {
                  "path": "./webpack.config.js"
                }
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "customWebpackConfig": {
                  "path": "./webpack.config.js"
                }
              }
            },
            "extract-i18n": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "bjjcastle:build"
              }
            },
            "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "src/test.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                "assets": [
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/assets"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.scss",
                  "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": []
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "tsconfig.app.json",
                  "tsconfig.spec.json",
                  "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            },
            "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "bjjcastle:serve"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "devServerTarget": "bjjcastle:serve:production"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }},
      "defaultProject": "bjjcastle"
    }
```

package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "bjjcastle",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.2",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.1.0",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.2",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.2",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^1.1.1",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.5.3"
      }
    }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
        module : {
          rules: [
            {
              test   : /\.scss$/,
              loader : 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                ident  : 'postcss',
                syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                plugins: () => [
                  require('postcss-import'),
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      };
```

The Error I receive:

```
    Schema validation failed with the following errors:

      Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget'.

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! errno 1

    npm ERR! bjjcastle@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`

    npm ERR! Exit status 1


    npm ERR!

    npm ERR! Failed at the bjjcastle@0.0.0 start script.

    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
    logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

    npm ERR!     C:\Users\MyRoute\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-16T05_27_51_621Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I'm also facing this exact same issue.

Comment: @LeroyMeijer I never worked output exactly what the issue was, I think I misread the documentation and copied only half of what I needed to. It’s been a while since I played around with this one though. Hope that helps.

Comment: Nevermind I got it fixed, a type so to call...... :S

Comment: @Jokz what fixed? can you post the files you ended with when you succeeded to start?

Comment: I'm not home right now, will check then. For now did you do a npm install in the correct folder? Also make sure the angular-cli is installed (globally) with: npm install -g @angular/cli   after that then do npm install. Also a different idea, just create a new angular project and compare configs. Also the fix in this issue can help. Let us know! 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61749199/tailwindcss-not-working-in-angular-lazy-loaded-child-component/61796382#61796382

Answer (score 9):

add `browserTarget` property in the options object

````
              "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "bjjcastle:build",
                "customWebpackConfig": {
                  "path": "./webpack.config.js"
                }
              }
            },```
````

Comment: Angular 13 seems not to have an Options element.

Answer (score 4):

For me it fixed by updating deprecated key from this `buildTarget` to this `browserTarget`

Comment: I think actually, it's the other way round actually:  `browserTarger` is outdated I think. But you can get this error when you use the wrong CLI version for instance.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, updating angular/cli to the latest version helped in my case.

Type in the command line:

`ng update @angular/cli`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same issue and realized that I was doing `npm i` in the wrong directory. This happened because I was using an online IDE, and thus, the angular CLI was in the root directory, and my project's `package.json` in a subdirectory.

I had forgotten to do the `npm i` in the subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same exact issue. I wanted to run a project which was with Angular version 8 but it is outdated

As everyone mentioning Error typically occurs due to a misconfiguration in the *angular.json* file. If you already have browserTarget in the file then you need to make sure that the Angular CLI version installed globally on your machine is compatible with the version of Angular used in your project.
I solved it by considering these:

Angular Packages: Updated all Angular-related packages (@angular/...) to version 12.2.13, which is a stable release in the Angular 12 series.

```
npm i @angular/cli@12.2.13 --force
```

TypeScript: Upgraded to TypeScript 4.2.4, compatible with Angular 12.

```
npm i typescript@4.2.4 --force
```

Other Dependencies: Updated testing and tooling packages like Jasmine, Karma, etc., to versions compatible with Angular 12.

@types/node: Updated to match Node.js version 12 using nvm.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue here.

The reason is that i was running a `Docker Container` as `Sudo`, so project files were created as `Sudo`.

I had to give permissions to the project folder (`sudo chdmod -R 777 project_folder_name`). Afterwards I ran `npm install`.

Everything working fine, now.