# Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'

Tags: angular, ionic7

I can't run my ionic serve because of this problem,

[image: Error_Screen_Shot]

```
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: [ng]   Data path "" must have required property browserTarget.  [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
```

I expect to run the code in my browser, and also I cant install another dependencies what should i do? even if i use ng serve it is still not works for me. *I have also update @angular dependencies still don't work for me*.

[image: angular.json]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget' error in Angular 8 when running ng serve or npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519454/how-to-fix-data-path-should-have-required-property-browsertarget-error-in)

Comment: Can you check the `angular.json` file and ensure that the `browserTarget` property is set correctly

Comment: @Jaykant unfortunately no browserTarget in angular.json, and i couldn't find how to set browserTarget properly.

Comment: Can you share your angular.json here ?

Comment: @Jaykant the second image is my angular.json

Comment: I have also checked my backup file of my project, both of them(backup and current) has no browserTarget but my back up file can run/serve without using browserTarget, maybe ts-evaluator gives me headache because before getting this problem i cant install any packages and dependencies because of @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10

Answer (score 3):

1. First Step:

   ```
   npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular --save-dev --force
   ```
2. Second Step:

   ```
   npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular --save-dev --force
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you have made any `npm audit fix --force`, you may have come to the following issue:

**Different version of build-angular**

[image]

If so, try to run `ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Worked for me!