# I started getting this error: Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How to fix it?
This is my angular.json file:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "recon-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/recon-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              
            },
            "development": {
              
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried reinstalling and updating all the packages but it didnt work

Comment: Was your project created with the Angular CLI and if yes, which version? Which Angular version has your project? (you can run `ng version` in the project directory and paste the result to the question) When was the last time it was working? What did you change so it stopped working?

Comment: Angular CLI: 17.0.9
Node: 20.10.0
Package Manager: npm 10.2.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.0.8

Comment: i dont know what made it to not work... i took a break and opened my project and started getting this issue

Comment: If you are using git, you can try to go back in history to the last working version, so the issue can be narrowed down further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget' error in Angular 8 when running ng serve or npm start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519454/how-to-fix-data-path-should-have-required-property-browsertarget-error-in)